# How can I indicate if a property of child component change in a method

Tags: html, angular, typescript

The child component is `app-google-maps-panel` and have 2 property:
father component:

```html
<div class="col-6">
  <app-google-maps-panel [longitude]="longitude" [latitude]="latitude"></app-google-maps-panel>
</div>
```

And in parent have a method:

```
search() {
  debugger;
  this.locationIqService.getGeoByAddress(this.searchAdress).subscribe({
    next: (res:Geo) => {
      this.latitude=res.latitude;
      this.longitude=res.longitude;
    },
    error: (error) => { console.log(`Error call LocationIQ ${error}`) },
    complete: () => { }
  });
}
```

How can actualize child component

Comment: Very difficult to understand your question. Please rephrase what is the problem and what you want to achieve. To initialize a variable assign some value to `latitude` and `longitude` that's declared outside of `search()`.

Comment: There is the method ngOnChanges provided by the interface OnChanges.
The function ngOnChanges is called when any data-bound property of a directive changes. You can get from this method previous and new value

Answer (score 0):

Each time the parent component properties (longitude, latitude) are updated, the child component will be updated (actualized). So If it's not the case, you should check this `this.locationIqService.getGeoByAddress(this.searchAdress)`
Make sure this call is working and returning the appropriate values

Comment: Exactly, the error was that it did not parse to number the properties latitude and longitude and for that reason it did not update the map.